# React.MEMO() fails to work with hooks inside of it (probably useDispatch) within KendoReact

Tags: reactjs, redux, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, memo

I have a child filter input componenet inside [kendo grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/) and my goa is stoping that components from rendering again and saving "input text" inside input field

```
   <GridColumn
      field="name"
      title="Document Name"
      headerCell={HeaderCell}
      className="tableCell"
      cell={LinkCell}
      filterCell={() =>  <SearchInput className={filtersToggler} /> }
      footerCell={(props) => <FooterCell {...props} colSpan={4} total={total}></FooterCell>}
    />
```

Now when I add some input inside that component, it passes value to the state called **word** and after 500 ms it triggers debounce and parses it to the redux state called "term"

```
const SearchInput = React.memo(() => {
  const [word, setWord] = useState('');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const deb = useCallback(
    debounce((text) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_TERM', term: text }), 1000),
    []
  );

  const handleText = (text) => {
    deb(text);
  };
  return (
    <input
      className="searchInput"
      value={word}
      type="search"
      placeholder="Search.."
      onChange={(e) => {
        handleText(e.target.value)
        setWord(e.target.value);
      }}></input>
  );
});

export default SearchInput;
```

Now, whenever redux state changes, it triggers useEffect inside of a kendo grid and gets new data from API.

```
  const searchWord = useSelector((state) => state.search.term);
  const classifications = useSelector((state) => state.search.classifications);
  const date = useSelector((state) => state.search.date);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = searchDocsByName(searchWord, date, classifications);
    data.then((i) => {
      setDocuments(i.data.data);
      setTotal(i.data.data.length);
    });
  }, [searchWord, date, classifications]);
```

So what's the problem? SearchInput Componenet rerenders even if its inside React.memo() and from the profiler I am getting that SearchInput rendered because "hook change".

I am totally stuck, I have no idea how to procced.

Comment: it does render on every change because of setWord(e.target.value), but prob you mean extra renders? how many times it renders for each letter you type in the input?

Comment: if I look at the example in the docs from kendo grid they pass the component name to filterCell, while you pass a function that return a component to filterCell. It depends on the implementation of GridColumn if this matter. You could change this to filterCell={SearchInput} to check it this gets rid of the rerender

Comment: hey jelte, for filter cell to inheirt props you need to pass a function with props argument but yeah that was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needlessly set local state with `const [word, setWord] = useState('');`, setWord will re render your component because local state changed. You can make the input an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Here is an example of what you can do:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { useCallback } = React;

const initialState = {};
const reducer = (state, { type, term }) => {
  console.log('in reducer', type, term);
  return state;
};
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      () => (next) => (action) => next(action)
    )
  )
);
const debounce = (fn, time) => {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), time);
  };
};
const SearchInput = React.memo(function SearchInput() {
  console.log('rendering SearchInput');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const deb = useCallback(
    debounce(
      (text) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_TERM', term: text }),
      1000
    ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <input
      className="searchInput"
      type="search"
      placeholder="Search.."
      onChange={(e) => {
        deb(e.target.value);
      }}
    ></input>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  return <SearchInput />;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this good answer, but actual answer was mistake with hacking up kendo componenets. I passed function into filter cell instead of just componenet.

Your input was much valued, and i corrected mistakes that you pointed out here with extra state etc.

ty